# How change component source based on an environment if clause in routes on vueJs?

Tags: vue.js

In a vue project, I have some environment variables.
I need to call components based on those.
How can I use `if` in router file that can change the component for the route?

```
{
  path: '',
  name: 'home',
  component: () => { 
    // Is it possible to do something like this?
    if (process.env.VUE_APP_THEME === 'sample') {import('@/view/sapmle/Home.vue')}
    else {import('@/view/Home.vue')}
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function must return a Promise in order for it to work. Therefore you could do:

```js
{
  path: '',
  name: 'home',
  component: () => { 
    if (process.env.VUE_APP_THEME === 'sample') {
      return import('@/view/sapmle/Home.vue');
    } else {
      return import('@/view/Home.vue');
    }
 }
}
```